# Deleting rows in TableViewController after Swiping them in TableViewCell

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, core-data, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm building an app with CoreData, using UITableViewController.swift and UITableViewCell.swift.

I'm trying to delete a row as in Clear to-do app by using UIPanGestureRecognizer in UITableViewCell.swift. I'm able to pan rows to the left and the right, but I'm not sure how I can get an indexPath for those selected rows and delete them in UITableViewController.swift where all the data is located.

EduDicTableViewCell.swift:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(EduDicTableViewCell.handlePan(_:)))

    recognizer.delegate = self
    addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

//MARK: - horizontal pan gesture methods
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // 1
    if recognizer.state == .Began {
        // when the gesture begins, record the current center location
        originalCenter = center
    }
    // 2
    if recognizer.state == .Changed {
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
        center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y)
        // has the user dragged the item far enough to initiate a delete/complete?
        deleteOnDragRelease = frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0
    }
    // 3
    if recognizer.state == .Ended {
        let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y,
                                   width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
        if deleteOnDragRelease {
            print("send it")



        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
            print("Bounced Back")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a delegate/protocol in your custom cell, which calls a suitable method in the table view controller:

Add a protocol definition to the cell:

```
protocol EduDicTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didSwipeDelete(cell: UITableViewCell)
}
```

and then add an (optional) `delegate` variable with this protocol:

```
var delegate : EduDicTableViewCellDelegate? = nil
```

In the `handlePan` method, add a line to call the delegate method when the pan is released:

```
if deleteOnDragRelease {
    print("send it")
    self.delegate?.didSwipeDelete(self)
} else ...
```

Note that the `didSwipeDelete` method passes `self` - the cell which was swiped.

In the table view controller, add the method to delete the cell (using the tableView's `indexPathForCell` method to get the `indexPath` corresponding to the cell which was swiped):

```
func didSwipeDelete(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
        print("didSwipeDelete \(indexPath.section) - \(indexPath.row)")
        // remove the object at this indexPath from the data source
        // and delete the corresponding table view row
        ...
    }
}
```

Amend the class definition for the table view controller to indicate that it adopts the protocol:

```
class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController, EduDicTableViewCellDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Finally, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, set the `delegate` variable on the cell to `self` (the table view controller):

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!